# Unable to add alert notification for the image size validation and its different types format before uploading it how can we implement

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, redux

code sandbox :  https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-lamport-ql5ep

I am facing this issue. I have attached the code  CodeSandbox link.
[image]
Tried to fix the issue in various methods and ways but it's not fixing. I am not able to know why it's getting an error I don't understand the exact issue in the code. Could anyone help with the solution?

**Unable to add alert notification for the image size validation and its different types format before uploading it how can we implement
size <5mb and file format jpeg/png. alert notification not working**

also tried this method inside it unable to upload images jpeg such as upto 2-3mb size.

```
 const isSupported = (file) => {
    let type = file?.type.split("/")[1];
    let allowedTypes = ["png", "jpg", "jpeg"];
    return allowedTypes.includes(type);
  };

  const ValidateSize = (file) => {
    var FileSize = file.files[0].size / 1024 / 1024; // in MiB
    const overSize = FileSize > 5;
    if (overSize) {
      alert("File size exceeds above 5MB");
    }
    return overSize;
  };

  const handleFileChange = (e) => {
    if (ValidateSize(e.target)) {
    return;
    }

    if (isSupported(e.target.files[0])) {
      window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
      const mimeType = e.target.files[0].type;
      let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
      alert("Only jpg/jpeg and png files are allowed!");
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

here i have a code snippet, i did the file type validation first than the file size, hope it will help

```
Filevalidation = () => {
    //getting the file input
    const fi = document.getElementById('image');
    const img = fi.value.split('.').pop().toLowerCase().toString();
    var imageExts = ['jpg', 'jpeg'];
    // Check if any file is selected. 
    if (fi.files.length > 0) {
        console.log(img)
        if (imageExts.indexOf(img) === -1) {
            alert('Only jpg/jpeg and png files are allowed!');
        } if (imageExts.indexOf(img) !== -1) {

            let i;
            for (i = 0; i <= fi.files.length; i++) {

                const fsize = fi.files.item(i).size;
                const file = Math.round((fsize / 1024));
                // The size of the file.
                if (file >= 5120) {
                    alert('One or more files are bigger than 5mb');

                } if (file < 5120) {
                    //upload file/s
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: unable to upload images jpeg such as upto 2-3mb size.

Comment: check this code pen https://codepen.io/Elnatan/pen/PoGyVNP it should work for the error change the isactive to string (chose true or false and it should work) isactive="true"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66131925/cropping-functionalityreact-easy-crop-is-not-working-when-i-try-to-upload-an-i